# another way to do this mapping of a two argument function

Tags: list-manipulation

Sorry, I'm just starting to learn mathematica.

I have the following two-argument function:

```
h[{x_, y_}] := x ^ y
```

When I do the following:

```
Map[h, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]
```

I get the expected output:

```
{1, 4, 9}
```

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong with the following rewrite of the above map expression (I want to learn how to use `#1` ... `#n` 's):

```
 #1 ^ #2 & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

the error messages I'm getting are:

> Function::slotn: "Slot number 2 in #1^#2& cannot be filled from
>   (#1^#2&)[{1,2}]"
>
> Function::slotn: "Slot number 2 in #1^#2& cannot be filled from
>   (#1^#2&)[{2,2}]."
>
> Function::slotn: "Slot number 2 in #1^#2& cannot be filled from
>   (#1^#2&)[{3,2}]."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to use Map[] that is possible too:

```
#[[1]]^#[[2]] & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

Comment: thanks! I do prefer to use Map[]

Comment: @johnpeter Why?  Apply is really more appropriate here, and you did explicitly say that you want to learn to use #1, #2, ..., #n, which will only be useful if you go with Apply.

Comment: i'm just starting to learn. :-) I guess in this particular case, I was trying to learn how to express the same Map expression differently using #'s.  Now I understand what I'm doing wrong, and all of the first 3 answers did help me!

Comment: @Artes I presume you mean worst for execution time? Given that `Map[]` auto compiles and `@@@` doesn't I don't think the streamlined tests on the linked page you gave tell the whole story. Other than that there are conceptual concerns. You could argue for Apply there as well, but one point here is that you never move away from the data as a `List` by keeping it conceptually simple with `Map[]`.

Comment: @SEngstrom If you don't believe, provide your own tests. You'll convince of that.

Comment: @Artes So yes to performace?

Comment: @SEngstrom Not only, there's no need to justify `@@@` is the best.

Comment: @Artes I get about a factor 2.6 faster for x*y with /@ over @@@. Apply wins by about 10% for a random 3x3 polynomial in x,y.

Comment: @SEngstrom `x*y` i.e. `Times`, that link showes that `Times` is `x 3` faster but `Power` `x 3` slower.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8707/discussion-between-sengstrom-and-artes)

Answer (score 12):

First of all, let's clarify that if you define `h` as

```
`h[{x_, y_}] := ...`
```

then it takes a *single* argument which is a list of two items.  If you define it as

```
`h[x_, y_] := ...`
```

then it takes two separate arguments.

`#n` denotes the `n`th argument in a pure function.  In the function call `(#1^#2)& [{2,3}]` you are passing the pure function a single argument.  `#2` won't have a value so you get an error.  If you pass it two arguments, everything is fine:  `(#1^#2)& [2, 3]`

Starting with a list of two items, such as `{2,3}`, you can use `Apply` to pass these two items to a function:

```
Apply[#1^#2 &, {2,3}]
```

An alternate notation for this is `#1^#2 & @@ {2,3}`.

You can also `Apply` at level `1`.  Check the docs details.

```
Apply[f, {{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}}, {1}]

(* ==> {f[1,2], f[3,4], f[4,5]} *)
```

A shorthand for the above is `f @@@ {{1,2}, {3,4}, {4,5}}`.

In conclusion, what you want is

```
#1^#2 & @@@ {{1,2}, {2,2}, {3,4}}
```

Comment: Apply at level one needs to be explicit if you don't use `@@@` notation: `Apply[f, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5}}, {1}]`

Comment: @SEngstrom Thanks!  That was a typo.

Comment: If one wants to avoid `Slot[]`: `Power @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 4}}` (i.e. what amr did).

Answer (score 9):

For educational purposes, here's a couple other ways to do this:

```
Power @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

```
Power[Sequence @@ #] & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

```
Cases[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}, List[x__] :> Power[x]]
```

```
# /. List -> Power & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

```
Replace[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}, List -> Power, {2}, Heads -> True]
```

Note that this kind of head replacement is essentially what `@@@` is doing, though `@@@` does it specifically at level 1.

```
MapThread[Power, Transpose[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]]
```

Power itself threads over lists:

```
{bases, exponents} = Transpose[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]
bases^exponents
```

Your functions aren't so awesome:

```
{bases, exponents} = Transpose[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]
(op[#1, #2] &)[bases, exponents]
```

You can make them awesome, `SetAttributes` method:

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[a_, b_] := op[a, b];

{bases, exponents} = Transpose[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]
f[bases, exponents]
```

`Thread` method:

```
{bases, exponents} = Transpose[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]
Thread[(op[#1, #2] &)[bases, exponents]]
```

Third argument to `Function` method:

```
{bases, exponents} = Transpose[{{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]
Function[{a, b}, op[a, b], Listable][bases, exponents]
```

Comment: I very much prefer the first bit.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Apply` (at the level `1` (`@@@`))  rather than `Map`, in terms of a pure function as you looking for:

```
#1^#2 & @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

> ```
> {1, 4, 9}
> ```

Instead of a pure function `#1^#2 &` one can simply write built-in `Power`. 
Your `h` function takes only one argument i.e. a two-element list, while the second one (a pure function) has two arguments, so that's why you need `Apply` instead of `Map`.

There is another way which sometimes appears even faster (not for `Power` but for `Times` and `Plus`)

```
#1^#2 & @@ # & /@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}
```

Similarly here one can use `Power` instead of `#1^#2 &`. 
Take a look at a related question on stackoverflow [How to remove the extra {} when Mapping a function to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765556/how-to-remove-the-extra-when-mapping-a-function-to-a-list).  One of the answers contains interesting benchmarks for the both methods and you can learn there that the canonical approach `@@@` is roughly `3` times faster for `Power`, while for `Times` and `Plus` the second one is `~4` times faster ( due to autocompilation of `Map` etc.).

Comment: That looks like a bit of cursing before the data comes around :)

Comment: @johnpeter also keep in mind that all the operators in mathematica have a `FullForm` representation (even operators you might not expect would have such a thing), and that you can just do, for example, `Power @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}`. Try `FullForm[HoldForm[out = #1^#2 & @@@ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2}}]]` to see what I'm talking about.