# Mapping a pure function with multiple slots

Tags: map

Here is a pure function with multiple slots:

```
(#1^2 + #2^2)&[3, 4]
```

> 25

But how can I map that pure function over lists of values? For example, say I want to map `(#1^2 + #2^2)&` over `x = {1, 2, 4}` and `y = {3, 4, 6}`. I have tried the following expressions, but none of them work:

```
Map[(#1^2 + #2^2) &, {1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}]
Map[(#1^2 + #2^2) &, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}}]
Map[(#1^2 + #2^2) &, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {4, 6}}]
```

The result I expect is obviously `{10, 20, 52}`.

Could some one help me with this?

Comment: (#1^2 + #2^2) & @@@ Transpose[{{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}}]

Comment: Also, don't forget that `x^2+y^2` works, too.

Comment: Related: [(5217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5217/121), [(10211)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10211/121), [(24939)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24939/121)

Answer (score 17):

```
MapThread[#1^2 + #2^2 &, {x, y}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, PatoCriollo.  I will remember this function definitely!

Comment: En mi pueblo al Pato Criollo le dicen catrasca

Comment: Thanks you, m_goldberg, it reads much more comfortable.

Comment: En mi pueblo (Quilmes) tambien @belisarius

Comment: Welcome to the [club](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo), then

Comment: Object `1` at position {2, `2`} in `3` has only `4` of required `5` dimensions.: Object x at position {2, 1} in MapThread[#1  + #2  & , {x, y}] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions.

Answer (score 12):

I like the following very much

```
{x, y} = {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}};
(#1^2 + #2^2) & @@@ Transpose[{x,y}]
```

Another thing which is highly unused is to attach `Attributes` to pure `Functions`

```
Function[{a, b}, a^2 + b^2, {Listable}][x, y]
```

You can stick with the `Slot` notation too, but you have to tell then that the variables in `Function` is a `Null` list which might look too awkward for some users (but I give this as dedication to Leonid, who uses this quite a bit)

```
Function[Null, #1^2 + #2^2, {Listable}][x, y]
```

and to really mess it up, I'd like to remind everyone, that you don't need to put the `Null` explicitly. Therefore, this is completely valid syntax

```
Function[, #1^2 + #2^2, {Listable}][x, y]
```

Comment: Isn't attaching {Listable} the same as using MapThread from PatoCriollo's answer?

Comment: @BlacKow Nope, try to do this with `MapThread`: `Function[{x, y}, x + y, {Listable}][1, {1, 2, 3}]`. On the other hand with `MapThread` you can specify the level of depth.

Comment: I'm really just starting to learn Mathematica so I have a confusing mix of Map,Apply,Thread in my head. I was just saying that there are two different families of possible solutions: based on Threading and based on Applying. Is it correct?

Comment: @BlacKow sort of. Consider `Map` to be your generic method for transforming everything in a list/expression, e.g. `f /@ a[q,r,s]` becomes `a[f[q], f[r], f[s]]` `Apply` changes the `Head` of an expression, e.g. `Times@@(a+b)` becomes `Times[a, b]`. So, it does not work on atomic expressions, i.e. if `AtomQ@e == True` `Apply` won't work on it. (`Map` doesn't have that restriction.) Otherwise, it is similar to `MapThread`. `Thread`, however, is in some ways a generic distribution function for lists, e.g. `Thread[a -> {q, r}]` becomes `{a->q, a->r}`. So, subtly different applications.

Comment: @rcollyer thank you, this was my thought as well. Substituting the ``Head`` versus ``Map``ping

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the responses, maybe it is more elegant this way?

For single slot:

```
#^2 & @ {1,2,4}

[Out]={1, 4, 16}
```

For multiple slots:

```
(#1^2 + #2^2) & @@ {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}}

[Out]= {10, 20, 52}
```

The following codes have same output:

```
MapThread[(#1^2 + #2^2) &, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}}]

Apply[(#1^2 + #2^2) &, {{1, 2, 4}, {3, 4, 6}}]
```

It seems that Apply and MapThread are exchangeable in this case!