# Functions of two arguments

Tags: function-construction

I am pretty weak on the notion of pure functions, etc. I found a clean solution to my problem so in a sense I've already answered my own question but I don't feel I'm on terra firma.

I wanted to take a random sample from a list of lists with a different sample size for each list in the list of lists. I did the following which is clean and readable by the cognoscenti. I'll probably have trouble understanding this in a year. Comments and/or suggestions of better ways will be appreciated.

```
listoflists = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}, {8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13}};

samplesizes = {2, 3, 1, 3};

out=Apply[RandomSample, Transpose[{listoflists, samplesizes}], {1}]
```

Comment: The best solution is the one in the answer.  I just wanted to note that you can write "`Apply` at level 1" as `RandomSample @@@ Transpose[{listoflists, samplesizes}]`.  I find this more readable because I don't have to scan to the end of the expression to find the `{1}` part.  It might not be easier to remember what it does in a year's time though.  I do in fact use this frequently when the `Transpose[{listoflists, samplesizes}]` part is already constructed and stored somewhere.

Comment: If it goes about clarity, also adding slots could help. `RandomSample[#, #2] & @@@` is longer but maybe one will find it better. Or `Table[RandomSample[listoflists[[i]], samplesizes[[i]]], {i, 4}]`

Comment: Duplicates: [(3217)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3217/121), [(10211)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10211/121), [(15556)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15556/121), [(26858)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26858/121), [(32569)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32569/121), [(71988)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71988/121)

Answer (score 5):

Probably:

```
MapThread[RandomSample, {listoflists, samplesizes}]
```

is easier to understand

Comment: Especially with this http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/

Comment: Greeeaat!:) I haven't seen it before

Comment: @Kuba The `Select[]` one is worth trying

Comment: @belisarius This question clearly has been asked many times before.  I posted several duplicate links above.  Please choose one and vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

With global warming, characters are endangered. Save one... :-)

```
Inner[RandomSample, listoflists, samplesizes, List]
```