# Map with multiple arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a function `f[m,n]` and a list of arguments `args = {{m1,n1},{m2,n2},{m3,n3},{m4,n4}, ...}` that I want to apply to it. I tried `f/@args`, but this yields `{f[{m1,n1}], ...}`. Is there a more elegant solution than defining the function as `f[{m,n}]`?

Comment: Have a look at `Sequence`.

Comment: Look up `@@@`. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(24939)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24939/121)

Comment: if you like the ```/@``` notation, you could use ```Apply[f] /@ args```.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
args = {{m1, n1}, {m2, n2}, {m3, n3}, {m4, n4}};

f @@@ args
```

> {f[m1, n1], f[m2, n2], f[m3, n3], f[m4, n4]}

```
Apply[f, args, {1}]
```

> {f[m1, n1], f[m2, n2], f[m3, n3], f[m4, n4]}

```
f @@ # & /@ args
```

> {f[m1, n1], f[m2, n2], f[m3, n3], f[m4, n4]}

```
f[Sequence @@ #] & /@ args
```

> {f[m1, n1], f[m2, n2], f[m3, n3], f[m4, n4]}

```
% == %% == %%% == %%%%
```

> True

Answer (score 5):

```
args = {{m1, n1}, {m2, n2}, {m3, n3}, {m4, n4}};
```

Since V 13.1 we could also `MapApply`

```
MapApply[f] @ args
```

{f[m1, n1], f[m2, n2], f[m3, n3], f[m4, n4]}

And since V 14.0 `ComapApply` to apply more than one function

```
ComapApply[{f, g}] /@ args
```

{{f[m1, n1], g[m1, n1]}, {f[m2, n2], g[m2, n2]}, {f[m3, n3],
g[m3, n3]}, {f[m4, n4], g[m4, n4]}}

For versions prior to 14.0:

```
Query[All, Apply /@ {f, g}] @ args
```

{{f[m1, n1], g[m1, n1]}, {f[m2, n2], g[m2, n2]}, {f[m3, n3],
g[m3, n3]}, {f[m4, n4], g[m4, n4]}}

Answer (score 2):

In addition:

```
args = {{m1, n1}, {m2, n2}, {m3, n3}, {m4, n4}};

MapThread[f, Transpose@args]

(* {f[m1,n1],f[m2,n2],f[m3,n3],f[m4,n4]} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use `BlockMap`:

```
args = {{m1, n1}, {m2, n2}, {m3, n3}, {m4, n4}};

BlockMap[Sequence @@ f @@@ # &, args, 2]

(*{f[m1, n1], f[m2, n2], f[m3, n3], f[m4, n4]}*)
```