# Applying a function to the second element of a list

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to apply a simple function to the second element of a list:

```
{#1, #2/5} &@{1, 2}
```

But this returns an error message.

```
Function::slotn: "Slot number 2 in {#1,#2/5}& cannot be filled from ({#1,#2/5}&)[{1,2}]."
```

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: `{#1, #2/5} &[1, 2]` or `{#1, #2/5} & @@ {1, 2}`

Comment: Also `{#1, #2/5} & @@ {1, 2}` or  `{#[[1]], #[[2]]/5} &@{1, 2}`

Comment: I see, now it works.

Comment: You could also use `MapAt[#/5&, {1, 2}, 2]`

Comment: `Apply[{#1, #2/5} &]@{1, 2}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This is *not* a duplicate of "another way to do this mapping of a two argument function". The OP is asking about applying a function to the second argument of a list, i.e. transforming some responses. The supposed duplicate discusses applying a two-argument function to all elements of a list of pairs.

Comment: @masterxilo If I recall my reasoning this question was likely to be closed as "easily found in the documentation" so instead I marked it as a duplicate of a closely related question which has answers that when understood could be applied to solve this one.  garej and Bob Hanlon both gave (in comments) solutions that are effectively duplicates [(24940)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24940/121) or [(24941)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24941/121).  As you can see I also tried to answer this specific question in a comment.  Do you have a nontrivial answer you wish to post that