# How to transform the $y$ values in a list of $(x,y)$ pairs

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

How can I transform

```
data = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

to

> `{{1, f[0]}, {0, f[1]}, {1, f[1]}}`

---

This is similar to [Applying a function to the second element of a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108583/applying-a-function-to-the-second-element-of-a-list) and [another way to do this mapping of a two argument function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24939/another-way-to-do-this-mapping-of-a-two-argument-function), but it's not the same question

Comment: `MapAt[f, data, {All, -1}]`

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
data /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, f@y}
```

and

```
data = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
MapAt[f, data, {All, 2}]
```

will fix the problems mentioned by masterxilo's answer

Comment: `MapAt[f, data, {All, -1}]` works as well.

Comment: @J.M. yep, I changed that because it was identical to Kuba's comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
{#1, f@#2} & @@@ data
```

But we can also generalize `MapAt` to do the job: Note that

`MapAt[f, data, {1, 2}] === {{1, f[0]}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}`

So we can use

```
MapAtP[f_, expr_, positionPattern_] := MapIndexed[
  If[MatchQ[#2, positionPattern], f@#1, #1] &, expr, Infinity]

MapAtP[f, data, {_, 2}]
```

---

**Aside**

David Wagner's “Power programming with Mathematica”

[Are you interested in purchasing David Wagner's "Power programming with Mathematica"?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat#22724)

mentions the following idiom as "a more Mathematica-like way" to transform on the values of a list of (x,y) data points.

```
data = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}};
data /. {x_, y_} -> {x, f@y}
(**)
{{1, f[1]}, {0, f[0]}, {1, f[1]}}
```

But it fails with lists of length exactly 2:

```
data = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
data /. {x_, y_} -> {x, f@y}
(**)
{{1, 0}, f[{1, 0}]}
```

Comment: your replacement rule should be ...`f@y`